# Absolute magnitudes of stars

Tags: star

Where to find comprehensive list of absolute magnitudes for stars of different spectral types?  I need published paper or web page with data and reference to the source.

Comment: Third entry on a google search: http://articles.adsabs.harvard.edu//full/1935ApJ....81..187A/0000197.000.html

Comment: No, I need something like this http://www.uni.edu/morgans/astro/course/Notes/section2/spectraltemps.html but with reference to the source.

Comment: everything you need to know about different spectral types: http://ned.ipac.caltech.edu/level5/Gray/frames.html but maybe thats a bit too much info?

Comment: Thanks! But this is more useful for me: http://www.astro.lu.se/~lennart/MVstars.html

Answer (score 6):

[VizieR](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/) is an online source for all sorts of astronomical data published in scientific papers. As you mentioned, The [HIPPARCOS catalogue](http://adsabs.harvard.edu/abs/1997yCat.1239....0E) contains visual magnitude data.

1. Open the query page for the [main HIPPARCOS catalogue](http://vizier.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/VizieR-3?-source=I/239/hip_main)
2. Select the fields you want (defaults are ok for you)
3. Hit submit to see the results
4. You can limit the number of results and format under *Preferences* on the left

This table gives you the measured visual magnitude, i.e. the **Apparent Magnitude** ($m_V$, `V` column). To convert that into **Absolute Magnitude** ($M_V$) you need to know the distance to the star. This can be calculated using the **Parallax** field (`Plx` column).

Here's the formula for you:

$$M_V = m_V + 5 * log_{10}( Plx / 100 )$$

You can easily dump the data into Excel or something, put a formula into an extra column and calculate the **Absolute Magnitude**.

Comment: You might also check out the Extended Hipparcos catalog ([XHIP](http://cdsarc.u-strasbg.fr/viz-bin/Cat?V/137D)). The main.dat file contains luminosities, spectral types, and temperatures, and the photo.dat file contains absolute magnitudes in Johnson bands. References are at the top of the linked page.

Answer (score 1):

I have found next list based on HIPPARCOS data:
http://www.astro.lu.se/~lennart/MVstars.html

Answer (score 1):

For me, the best and most reliable source of absolute magnitudes and spectral types is the book [Allen's astrophysical quantities](http://adsabs.harvard.edu//abs/2000asqu.book.....C).

Chapter 15, called Normal Stars, contains spectral types, absolute magnitudes, colors and effective temperatures for main sequence, giant and supergiant stars. The references are at the end of the chapter.

HTH,

Germán.

Comment: Sure! But this is old data (as I remember around 1970). I tried to find new.

Comment: 4th edition of the book is from 2000. If you know anything newer than that, please make me know :)

Comment: 4th edition of the book (2000) also uses old data. It's easy to check.

Comment: How do you check then?

Comment: Just read the book )

Comment: I _use_ that book for my scientific research :)